# Creating multi-line header for JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I use JTable GUI component with NetBeans.

- I want to create multi-line headers
- I am able to this, when I create custom renderer for table headers
- BUT I don't want to, because I like default one (I use it everywhere else in program).
- So the problem is : **How to make
  header heigher?**

My code :

```
String headers[] = new String[3];
    headers[0] = "Header1";
    headers[1] = "Header2";
    headers[2] = "<html><center>Long<br>Centered</br></center></html>";
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(headers);
    dtm.setRowCount(5);
    jTable1.setModel(dtm);
    jTable1.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(
                new Dimension(jTable1.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth(),32));
```

Comment: Never mind, I updated my answer again :) Check if it looks as expected now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(
      new Dimension(table.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth(), 32));
```

This will change the size of the header:

[image]

To center the text, you can use the `<center>`-tag:

```
headers[2] = "<html><center>Long Centered<br>Header";
```

[image]

**EDIT**:

The alignment is set by your LookAndFeel. `WindowsTableHeaderUI` for example explicitly calls

```
setHorizontalAlignment(LEADING);
```

The easiest way to solve this is:

```
(JLabel)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer())
      .setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

Note that this change is lost when you change your LookAndFeel afterwards.

Comment: Great, thanx that's what I need.
However, I am now having quite trouble center text in header ...
Is there any chance you know how to?

Comment: html <center> tag wont help ...
SwingConstants.CENTER would, but I would againg need to create own renderer for headers :/

Comment: I tried `center` and it worked: `"<html><center>Long<br>Header</br></html>"`. Have you tried like this?

Comment: headers[0] = "<html>Monday<br>"+week[0]+"</br></html>";
Does not work for me :/
My headers are resizable btw

Comment: Peter you helped me once again, I am thankful :)
It is correct as you suggest 

((JLabel)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER); solves it

Answer (score 1):

hi guys i tried this and it works:

```
    DefaultTableCellRenderer r;

    String headers[] = new String[3];
    headers[0] = "Category";
    headers[1] = "Item";
    headers[2] = "<html><center>Packaging<br>unit</center></br></html>";
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
    table.setModel(dtm);
    r = (DefaultTableCellRenderer)table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
    r.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(headers);

    table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(table.getColumnModel().getTotalColumnWidth(),32));
```