# JTable header text wrapping for multiline header (custom TableCellRenderer)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

How can I obtain a multiline JTable header where the header column correctly enlarges to fit some text and then wraps to a new line?

Something like shown below:

[image: wrapping column header]

Currently searching for the above requirements returns a lot of solutions of which none really solves the problem:

http://www.javarichclient.com/multiline-column-header/

[Creating multi-line header for JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343391/creating-multi-line-header-for-jtable)

[Java JTable header word wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26213916/java-jtable-header-word-wrap)

The above solutions all propose using HTML code, for instance:

```
String[] columnNames = {
    "<html><center>Closing<br>Date</html>",
    "<html><center>Open<br>Price</html>",
    "<html>Third<br>column</html>"
};
```

That solution is not elegant for a couple of reasons, mainly because in the case of variable columns names I need to pass the string to a function which strips spaces and subtitutes them with `<br>` symbols, however if the column text contains very short text that appears in a line of its own.

I would need to decide a minimum and a maximum length of a column and then be able to make text centering possible, the above solution quickly becomes overengineered and unmanageable.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiLineHeaderTable.htm

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/MultiLineHeaderExample.htm

[image: multilineheader2]

Above solutions require manually creating a header array with words already correctly split up as in:

```
  public static Object[][] tableHeaders = new Object[][] {
      new String[] { "Currency" },
      new String[] { "Yesterday's", "Rate" },
      new String[] { "Today's", "Rate" },
      new String[] { "Rate", "Change" } };
```

-or-

```
DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
    dm.setDataVector(
        new Object[][] { { "a", "b", "c" }, { "A", "B", "C" } },
        new Object[] { "1st\nalpha", "2nd\nbeta", "3rd\ngamma" });
```

Still not elegant because variable text in the column names would not be feasible.

[How to change JTable header height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686535/how-to-change-jtable-header-height)

Manually setting the header height as in the above solutions is only half of what I want to do, because then text would still not correctly wrap and deciding the height is still not feasible.

Currently all I was able was to create a custom TableCellRenderer but yet no solution:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

/**
 * @version 1.0 11/09/98
 */
public class MultiLineHeaderExample extends JFrame
{

    MultiLineHeaderExample()
    {
        super("Multi-Line Header Example");

        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dm.setDataVector(new Object[][]
        {
            {
                "a", "b", "c"
            },
            {
                "A", "B", "C"
            }
        },
        new Object[]
                {
                    "My First Column, Very Long But Space Separated", "short col", "VeryLongNoSpaceSoShouldSomeHowWrap"
        });

        JTable table = new JTable(dm);
        MultiLineHeaderRenderer renderer = new MultiLineHeaderRenderer();
        Enumeration enumK = table.getColumnModel().getColumns();
        while (enumK.hasMoreElements())
        {
            ((TableColumn) enumK.nextElement()).setHeaderRenderer(renderer);
        }
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll);
        setSize(400, 110);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MultiLineHeaderExample frame = new MultiLineHeaderExample();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}

class MultiLineHeaderRenderer extends JList implements TableCellRenderer
{

    public MultiLineHeaderRenderer()
    {
        ListCellRenderer renderer = getCellRenderer();
        ((JLabel) renderer).setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        setCellRenderer(renderer);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
    {
        setFont(table.getFont());
        String str = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str));
        String line;
        Vector v = new Vector();
        try
        {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                v.addElement(line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        setListData(v);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This here also uses `JTextArea` and also resizes the header height when the table is resized. The key to the correct calculation of the table header height is `setSize(width, getPreferredSize().height);`

```
class MultiLineTableHeaderRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer
{
  public MultiLineTableHeaderRenderer() {
    setEditable(false);
    setLineWrap(true);
    setOpaque(false);
    setFocusable(false);
    setWrapStyleWord(true);
    LookAndFeel.installBorder(this, "TableHeader.cellBorder");
  }

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    int width = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getWidth();
    setText((String)value);
    setSize(width, getPreferredSize().height);
    return this;
  }
}
```

Comment: Works great, only problem is that it uses JTextArea to display text in the header, so the columns header styling will be lost and a white background for instance will be used.

Comment: I edited the answear to make the header look like default header of a `JTable`.

Comment: @sarah.ferguson Try set the JTextArea's background to `JTable.getBackground()`.

Comment: To give the header the same color as the `JTable` I used `setOpaque(false)`. See edited code above.

Answer (score 2):

you need a Conponent that is able to wordwrap its content like JTextArea.
I changed the cell renderer from your SSCCE so that is works initially, but it has a nasty resize behavior.

```
 class MultiLineHeaderRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer {
    public MultiLineHeaderRenderer()
    {
        setAlignmentY(JLabel.CENTER);
        setLineWrap(true);
        setWrapStyleWord(true);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK),
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(3,3,3,3)
                ));

    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus,
            int row,
            int column) {
        setFont(table.getFont());
        String str = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
        setText(str);
        int columnWidth= getColumnWidth();
        setRows(str.length()/columnWidth);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. This solution has the following advantages:

1. You need not manually break the column names.
2. The columns dynamically word-wrap as you resize the columns and/or window.
3. The header appearance will automatically be consistent with the installed look-and-feel.
4. Unlike other solutions I have seen, this works even if the first column doesn't wrap (as in the example below).

It has the following disadvantage, however: It creates an unused JTableHeader object for each column, so it's a bit inelegant and probably not suitable if you have many columns.

The basic idea is that you wrap the column names in an `<html>` tags, and, crucially, every `TableColumn` gets its own `TableCellRenderer` object.

I came to this solution after debugging deep into the guts of the Swing table header layout plumbing. Without getting too much into the weeds, the problem is that if the `TableColumn`s don't have a headerRenderer defined, the same default renderer is used for every column header cell. The layout code used for `JTableHeader` only bothers to ask the renderer of the *first* column header for its preferred size (see feature 4. above), and because the renderer is re-used, the call to its `setText()` method triggers the creation of a new `View` for the label, which, for reasons I'm too tired to even think about explaining, causes the header renderer to always report its preferred *unwrapped* height.

Here is a quick-and-dirty proof-of-concept:

```
package scratch;

import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class WordWrappingTableHeaderDemo extends JFrame {

    class DemoTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private ArrayList<String> wrappedColumnNames = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        private int numRows;

        DemoTableModel(List<String> columnNames, int numRows) {
            for (String name: columnNames)
                wrappedColumnNames.add("<html>" + name + "</html>");
            this.numRows = numRows;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return numRows;
        }

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return wrappedColumnNames.size();
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return Integer.valueOf(10000 + (rowIndex + 1)*(columnIndex + 1));
        }

        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return wrappedColumnNames.get(column);
        }

        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    }

    public WordWrappingTableHeaderDemo() {

        DefaultTableColumnModel tableColumnModel = new DefaultTableColumnModel() {
            public void addColumn(TableColumn column) {
                // This works, but is a bit kludgey as it creates an unused JTableHeader object for each column:
                column.setHeaderRenderer(new JTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer());
                super.addColumn(column);
            }
        };

        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);;
        table.setColumnModel(tableColumnModel);
        table.setModel(
                new DemoTableModel(Arrays.asList("Name", "The Second Column Name is Very Long", "Column Three"), 20));
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        WordWrappingTableHeaderDemo app = new WordWrappingTableHeaderDemo();
        app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        app.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        app.pack();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {createAndShowGUI();});
    }
}
```