# TableColumn.setHeaderRenderer vs. JTableHeader.setDefaultRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer, jtableheader

While working on a solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144558/jtable-header-text-wrapping-for-multiline-header-custom-tablecellrenderer), I ran across some strange behaviour with JTableHeader rendering. Rendering output is different when using TableColumn.setHeaderRenderer vs. JTableHeader.setDefaultRenderer with the same renderer. I've confirmed the renderer is being used in both cases. The desired output is produced when using TableColumn.setHeaderRenderer. Can anyone explain why there would be any difference in output? Should one prefer TableColumn.setHeaderRenderer over JTableHeader.setDefaultRenderer? What am i missing?

Invoke the following code with any argument to see the TableColumn.setHeaderRenderer output. No argument will use the JTableHeader.setDefaultRenderer

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class MultiLineHeaderExample extends JFrame
{
    public MultiLineHeaderExample( boolean addRendererToTableColumn )
    {
        super( "Multi-Line Header Example" );

        DefaultTableModel dm = new DefaultTableModel();
        dm.setDataVector( new Object[][]
                {
                    {
                        "a", "b", "c"
                    },
                    {
                        "A", "B", "C"
                    }
                },
            new Object[]
                {
                    "short col", "My First Column, Very Long But Space Separated", "VeryLongNoSpaceSoShouldSomeHowWrap"
                } );

        JTable table = new JTable( dm );
        MultiLineTableHeaderRenderer renderer = new MultiLineTableHeaderRenderer();

        if( addRendererToTableColumn )
        {//if renderer is set on each column, desired rendering is observed
            table.getColumnModel().getColumns().asIterator().forEachRemaining( column -> column.setHeaderRenderer( renderer ) );
        }
        else
        {
            //if set as default renderer for header, incorrect rendering is observed
            table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer( renderer );
        }

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scroll );
        setSize( 400, 110 );
        setVisible( true );
    }


    public static final class MultiLineTableHeaderRenderer extends JTextArea implements TableCellRenderer
    {
        public MultiLineTableHeaderRenderer()
        {
            setEditable( false );
            setLineWrap( true );
            setOpaque( false );
            setFocusable( false );
            setWrapStyleWord( true );
            LookAndFeel.installBorder( this, "TableHeader.cellBorder" );
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column )
        {
            int width = table.getColumnModel().getColumn( column ).getWidth();
            setText( ( String ) value );
            setSize( width, getPreferredSize().height );
            return this;
        }
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () ->
        {
            MultiLineHeaderExample frame = new MultiLineHeaderExample( args.length > 0 );
            frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter()
            {
                public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e )
                {
                    System.exit( 0 );
                }
            } );
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Remember that the render is shared across ALL the columns - so when using the `default` workflow, you're taking one instance of the render and applying it across all the columns as apposed to setting an individual instance of the render per column - why does this matter?  Because the size of each render changes per column.  Personally, I'm not sure I'd be using `JTextArea` for this and I'd be concerned about setting the `preferredSize` so directly, having said that, I don't have an alternative solution at hand

Comment: I'm not sure that explains the behavior. When setting the renderer on each column, it is still the same instance across all of them, not a separate one per column. Functionally, the two methods of setting the renderer appear to be the same to me.